# How do you use DC when you cast a spell

Tags: dnd-5e, saving-throw, difficulty-class

Say I use a spell that requires target to make a DEX save or take 2d6 fire dmg. What would I compare that creatures DEX save to?

Example: I cast a spell that says, "Target creature makes a DEX saving throw, if fails, take 2d6 fire dmg". What would I compare the targets DEX roll to?

Comment: I’ve undeleted this because duplicates are valued here. They help others find the answers faster by having more ways to search for them. Thanks for helping the site work better!